# datatables button breaking search functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to add download buttons to my table, however when I do so, my column search functionality breaks and the buttons do not show. I also tried implementing the buttons using DOM but that replaced my table size dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "buttons": [
            "copy",
            "csv",
            "xls",
            "pdf"
        ]
    }); 
    $('#search-category').on('change',function(){
        table
        .column(3)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    }),
    $('#search-sub-category').on('change',function(){
        table
        .column(4)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    })
} );
```

(Without buttons: https://jsfiddle.net/jkczwtbt/)
Any pointers where I am not understanding the documentation?

https://datatables.net/reference/button/excel
https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things which you missed.

1. You don't ask the DataTables to actually insert the buttons into the DOM. That's why they don't show up.

You have to add the "dom" option with a capital "B". See section "Displaying the buttons" on [Buttons Extansion](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) for more information and other methods of implementation.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
    'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
]
```

} );

2. You do not use the correct predefined options which is the reason your code breaks. You have to use "excel" and not "xls" option.

If you want to change the default button name for the Excel button to XLS you have to initiate the button in a different way. See [Examples on the Buttons reference page](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excel). One way would be to do it like this:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'XLS'
    }
]
```

} );

A working result you can find on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2755sx8/1/).

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'copy',
    {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'XLS'
    }
  ]
 });
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks, however it hits the issue I had previously whilst using 'Bfrtip' where the selector of table size gets replaced by the download button. Is there a method to show both?

Comment: @user3770935 just use dom: 'Blfrtip'
Where l means length i.e. size dropdown.